# How to write to one value in a JSON file with LibGDX

Tags: json, libgdx

For example, if I have this JSON file:

```
{
  "player": {
    "gold":100,
    "diamonds":100,
    "username":"placeholder"
  }
}
```

And the player's gold amount was modified and I wanted to overwrite ONLY the gold value, how would I code that?

Here is what I have so far but it overwrites the whole JSON file, whereas I only want to overwrite one value.

```
   public void save(Player player, String path) {
        Json json = new Json();
        String txt = json.toJson(player);
        FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local(path);
        file.writeString(json.prettyPrint(txt), true);
    }
```

Comment: only change value of gold data member in player object and save(overwrite).

Comment: @Aryan could you explain further? When I save it overwrites the whole file.

Comment: @Sixteen You can't do that. Your current solution is the right one, that's what Aryan wanted to say. You shouldn't worry about performance at this point, unless writing this data becomes a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

You've to overwrite the complete file so it's better to use a separate file for your player.

Like this `player.json`

```
{
    "gold":100,
    "diamonds":100,
    "username":"placeholder"
}
```

And `Player.java`

```
public class Player {

    public int gold;
    public int diamonds;
    public String username;
}
```

Use below code that will modify and save data to a json file.

```
Json json = new Json();
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("player.json");
Player player = file.exists()? json.fromJson(Player.class,file) : new Player();
player.gold=300;       // modify player data

save(player,file);
```

After then call save method, given below :

```
private void save(Player player, FileHandle file) {
    Json json = new Json();
    json.setTypeName(null);
    json.setUsePrototypes(false);
    json.setIgnoreUnknownFields(true);
    json.setOutputType(JsonWriter.OutputType.json);

    String txt = json.toJson(player);
    file.writeString(json.prettyPrint(txt), false);
}
```